# Detecting if a variable can be printed in Lua

Tags: string, types, lua

I've got a variable that could be a number of types - sometimes it's a string, sometimes a number, table or bool. I'm trying to print out the value of the variable each time like this:

```
print("v: "..v)
```

with `v` being my variable. Problem is, when I get a value that can't be concatenated I get this error:

> myscript.lua:79: attempt to concatenate a table value

I've tried changing it to this in case it manages to detect whether or not the variable can be printed:

```
print("v: "..(v or "<can't be printed>"))
```

but I had the same problem there. Is there some sort of function I can use to determine if a variable can be concatenated to a string, or a better way of printing out variables?

Comment: print("v: " .. (tostring(v) or "No print")) might work. Although I don't know what tostring returns with a table as argument.

Comment: @FrederikSpang - Why `or`ing?  Simply `print('v = '..tostring(v))`

Comment: Because I was unaware of the result from a table input. I haven't done lua for quite some time - @EgorSkriptunoff

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can provide the values as separate arguments to print:

```
print("v:", v)
```

This would print something like

```
v:  table: 006CE900
```

Not necessarily the most useful, but better than a crash if it's just for debugging purposes.

[See here for information on more useful table printing.](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization)

Answer (score 6):

tostring(v) works for all possible v values (including nil). So writing your line as:

print( "v: " .. tostring( v ) )

will always work.

Alternatively you could have a look at type( v ) and if its "string" print it, otherwise print something else (if that's what you want).

Comment: This should be marked as the answer, in my opinion!